# All unique combinations of the products of two lists

Tags: python, list, combinations

To preface, there are elements of this problem that lead me to believe that this seemingly duplicate question isn't actually redundant of others on the site.

I have two lists, each of the same length (4 elements each), where each element is a complex number. For each element in the second list, it is the conjugate of the respective element in the first list.

Ex.

```
N = [5,17,37,89]
list1 = [getFactors(f) for f in N]
list2 = [conjugate(getFactors(f)) for f in N]

print(list1)
print(list2)
>[1 + 2*I, 4 + I, 6 + I, 8 - 5*I]
>[1 - 2*I, 4 - I, 6 - I, 8 + 5*I]

print(simplify(list1[0]*list2[1]*list2[2]*list2[3]))
print(simplify(list2[0]*list1[1]*list1[2]*list1[3]))
>164 + 503*I
>164 - 503*I
```

I want to choose one element from each list, either the complex number or its conjugate from the second list, and then multiply them all against one another.

So there are 2^4 = 16 total combinations I can make, however, if the product is the conjugate of some other combination, I want to disregard it.

```
print(simplify(test1[0]*test2[1]*test2[2]*test2[3]))
print(simplify(test2[0]*test1[1]*test1[2]*test1[3]))
>164 + 503*I
>164 - 503*I
```

What code can I write to get the 8 unique combinations from the product of the possible choices of elements from each list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use complex number (native python) with its `.conjugate()` to filter out the duplicates. Also, `itertools.product()` is helpful to enumerate all the combinations needed.

```py
import math
import itertools

list1 = [1 + 2j, 4 + 1j, 6 + 1j, 8 - 5j]
list2 = [1 - 2j, 4 - 1j, 6 - 1j, 8 + 5j]
lst = [list1, list2] # lst[0] == list1

n = len(lst[0]) # 4
output = []
for choiceplan in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=n): # choiceplan == e.g., (0, 1, 1, 0)
    product = math.prod(lst[choiceplan[i]][i] for i in range(n))
    if product not in output and product.conjugate() not in output:
        output.append(product)

print(output) # [(304+433j), (-256+463j), (428+311j), (-92+521j), (472+239j), (-8+529j), (524+73j), (164+503j)]
```

In the code, `choiceplan` is a tuple containing 0 and 1 to indicate from which list an element is to be picked. So `lst[choiceplan[i]][i]` chooses the `i`-th element from the list which `choiceplan` prescribes at `i`.